# $X$ is uniformly convex Banach space. If $f$ is nonzero bounded functional, then there is $x\in S_{X}$ such that $f(x)=\|f\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, proof-explanation

I have a question regarding the proof of the following:

> $X$ is a uniformly convex Banach space. If $f$ is nonzero bounded functional, then there is $x\in S_{X}=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ such that  $f(x)=\|f\|$

Proof: Let $x_n \in S_X$ be such that $f(x_n)\to \|f\|$. It's sufficient to show that $x_n$ is Cauchy.

Suppose not, so that there is $\epsilon >0$ and increasing $n_k,m_k$ such that $\|x_{n_k}-x_{m_k}\|\ge \epsilon$ for all $k\ge 1$. Let $y_k=(x_{n_k}+x_{m_k})/2$. Then $\|y_k\|\le 1$ and $f(y_k)\to \|f\|$.

*It follows that* $\|y_k\|\to 1$. But I don't understand how this follows;

Comment: I suppose $S_X = \{ x \in X \mid \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$?

Comment: @Demophilus Yes, the unit sphere in $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\lvert f(y_k) \rvert \leq \lVert f \rVert \lVert y_k \rVert$. So we have $\frac{\lvert f(y_k) \rvert}{\lVert f \rVert} \leq \lVert y_k \rVert \leq 1$. So letting $k \to \infty$, results in $\lim_{k \to \infty} \lVert y_k \rVert = 1$.

Comment: I suppose you meant $|f(y_k)|\le \|f\|\|y_k\|$?

Comment: Yes of course, I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Because, if there were a subsequence $y_{k_u}$ such that $0<\sup_{k\in\Bbb N}\lVert y_{k_u}\rVert=\alpha<1$, then $$\lvert f(y_{k_u})\rvert=\lVert y_{k_u}\rVert \left\lvert f\left(\frac{y_{k_u}}{\lVert y_{k_u}\rVert}\right)\right\rvert\le\alpha\left\lvert f\left(\frac{y_{k_u}}{\lVert y_{k_u}\rVert}\right)\right\rvert\le\alpha\lVert f\rVert<\lVert f\rVert$$

Against the hypothesis $f(y_k)\to\lVert f\rVert$.